# Quiero enviar un archivo en un JSON por medio de una AJAX sin usar formData, ¿es posible?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, formularios

Tengo un formulario que envio con un **ajax**. Los datos los extraigo con **jQuery** y los meto en prototipo para enviarlos en **ajax** con un **dataType**: '**json**'. Vamos lo normal.

```js
     var datos = {
        nombre : $('#nombre').val()
     }
    $.ajax({
        url: '../js/file.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: dato,
    })
    .complete(function() {
        console.log("success");
    })
```

```html
<form action="" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="text" id="nombre">
    <button type="submit">enviar</button>
</form>
```

Pero ahora quiero enviar un archivo en el formulario pero usando el mismo prototipo y lo hago asi

```js
 var datos = {
        nombre : $('#nombre').val(),
        foto :  $('#foto').prop('files')[0],

     }
```

ahora en el momento del envio del **ajax** me da este error

> jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

ahora entiendo que tengo que convertir el archivos en binario para que pueda ser enviado al servidor y por eso se usa el objeto form data. Mi pregunta es si a estas alturas no existe otro método? pues tengo entendido que form data es tecnologia XMLHttpRequest. Gracias

Comment: te fijaste que tu variable se llama **datos** y en el `data` del ajax pones **dato** sin la **s**

Comment: ha si, pero eso es que copie mal el ejemplo. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando JSON

Pues yo lo he hecho transformando el archivo en Base64 y mandandolo como string

[Por ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36281449/3100840):

```
function getBase64(file) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   reader.onload = function () {
     console.log(reader.result);
   };
   reader.onerror = function (error) {
     console.log('Error: ', error);
   };
}
```

Y tu json quedaria mas o menos asi:

```
"data:text/plain;base64,aG9sYQ=="
```

---

La configuración que uso es la siguiente:

El form que tenga `enctype="multipart/form-data"` y de preferencia que quede en POST para que no pase algo raro, quedando:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" id="nombre">
    <button type="submit">enviar</button>
</form>
```

Removí `accept-charset="utf-8"` no se si afecte, pero puedes hacer tus pruebas y contarnos.

Y en nuestro código javascript

```
        $('#nuestroForm').on('submit',(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); //importante 
            var formData = new FormData(this);

            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url: 'nuestra url',
                data:formData,
                cache:false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success:function(data){
                    console.log("success");
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(data){
                    console.log("error");
                    console.log(data);                      
                }
            });
        }));
```

Mira que yo no tengo dataType: 'json' y asi funciona.

[Documentación de ajax en jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> **processData** (default: true)
>
> Type: Boolean By default, data passed in
>
> to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a
>   string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting
>   to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If
>   you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this
>   option to false.
>
> **contentType** (default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
>   charset=UTF-8')
>
> Type: Boolean or String
>
> When sending data to the
>   server, use this content type. Default is
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", which is fine for
>   most cases. If you explicitly pass in a content-type to $.ajax(), then
>   it is always sent to the server (even if no data is sent). As of
>   jQuery 1.6 you can pass false to tell jQuery to not set any content
>   type header. Note: The W3C XMLHttpRequest specification dictates that
>   the charset is always UTF-8; specifying another charset will not force
>   the browser to change the encoding. Note: For cross-domain requests,
>   setting the content type to anything other than
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain
>   will trigger the browser to send a preflight OPTIONS request to the
>   server.

Comment: claro amigo. Mi pregunta es si no existe un metodo para enviarlo por JSON. Esa es la pregunta.

Comment: @Sr.K Dame un segundo y edito

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS AMIGO! era justo lo que queria

Comment: de que forma preparas el archivo para que sea convertido en a base64??? `document.getElementById('upload').files[0]` hago eso  pero me dice un error al ejecutar `readAsDataURL(file)`

Comment: @Stevn aqui esta el ejemplo completo funcionando de la conversion a base 64 http://jsbin.com/piqiqecuxo/1/edit?js,console,output